# How to connect a Subscriber with a reactor.core.publisher.Flux?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I want to connect a Subscriber with a Reactor Flux. However my little example doesn't produce any output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Flux.just("a", "b", "c")
            .subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription ignored) {
                }

                @Override
                protected void hookOnNext(String value) {
                    System.out.print(value);
                }
            });
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I tried the same with an [org.reactivestreams.Subscriber](http://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html):

```
    Flux.just("a", "b", "c")
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
            });
```

But again, no output.

If I try the simplest from:

```
Flux.just("a", "b", "c").subscribe(System.out::println);
```

... it produces the expected output:

```
a
b
c
```

How can I use a Subscriber to receive the values from the Flux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to `request` n more values from the source. Until that call nothing happens.

Example with `BaseSubscriber`:

```
Flux<String> source = Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
source.subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                request(1); // <-- here
            }

            @Override
            protected void hookOnNext(String value) {
                request(1); // <-- here
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        });
```

And the same with a standard `Subscriber`:

```
Flux<String> source = Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
source.subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
    private Subscription subscription;

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        subscription.request(1); // <-- here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        subscription.request(1); // <-- here
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
    }
});
```

Comment: that is correct. additionally if you want the source to emit as fast as possible you can do a `requestUnbounded()` in `BaseSubscriber.hookOnSubscribe` (no need for more `request` after that)